# TypeError: Cannot read property 'games' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

hi so i have this code running an akinator game and downloaded the `aki-api` but i get this error when starting the game:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'games' of undefined`

here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { Aki } = require('aki-api');
const { list, verify } = require('../../discord bot/commands/functions.js');
const regions = ['person', 'object', 'animal'];

module.exports = {
        name: 'aki',
        description: 'Think About A Real or Fictional Character, I Will Try To Guess It',
        async execute(message, args, Discord, client, ops) {
        // if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('EMBED_LINKS')) return message.channel.send('**Missing Permissions - [EMBED_LINKS]!**');
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`**What Category Do You Want To Use? Either \`${list(regions, 'or')}\`!**`);
        let stringAki = args[0].toLowerCase();
        let region;
        if (stringAki === 'person'.toLocaleLowerCase()) region = 'en';
        if (stringAki === 'object'.toLocaleLowerCase()) region = 'en_objects';
        if (stringAki === 'animal'.toLocaleLowerCase()) region = 'en_animals';
        if (!regions.includes(stringAki)) return message.channel.send(`**What Region Do You Want To Use? Either \`${list(regions, 'or')}\`!**`);
        const current = ops.games.get(message.channel.id);
        if (current) return message.channel.send(`**Please Wait Until The Current Game of \`${current.name}\` is Finished!**`);
        try {
            const aki = new Aki(region);
            let ans = null;
            let win = false;
            let timesGuessed = 0;
            let guessResetNum = 0;
            let wentBack = false;
            let forceGuess = false;
            const guessBlacklist = [];
            ops.games.set(message.channel.id, { name: 'akinator' });
            while (timesGuessed < 3) {
                if (guessResetNum > 0) guessResetNum--;
                if (ans === null) {
                    await aki.start();
                } else if (wentBack) {
                    wentBack = false;
                } else {
                    try {
                        await aki.step(ans);
                    } catch {
                        await aki.step(ans);
                    }
                }
                if (!aki.answers || aki.currentStep >= 79) forceGuess = true;
                const answers = aki.answers.map(answer => answer.toLowerCase());
                answers.push('end');
                if (aki.currentStep > 0) answers.push('back');
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setColor('GREEN')
                    .setDescription(`**Q${aki.currentStep + 1} - ${aki.question}**\n${aki.answers.join(' | ')}${aki.currentStep > 0 ? ` | Back` : ''} | End`)
                    .setFooter(`Yes/No To Confirm | Progress - ${Math.round(Number.parseInt(aki.progress, 10))}%`)
                await message.channel.send(embed)
                const filter = res => res.author.id === message.author.id && answers.includes(res.content.toLowerCase());
                const messages = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 30000
                });
                if (!messages.size) {
                    await message.channel.send('**Time Up!**');
                    win = 'time';
                    break;
                }
                const choice = messages.first().content.toLowerCase();
                if (choice.toLowerCase() === 'end'.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                    forceGuess = true;
                } else if (choice.toLowerCase() === 'back'.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                    if (guessResetNum > 0) guessResetNum++;
                    wentBack = true;
                    await aki.back();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    ans = answers.indexOf(choice);
                }
                if ((aki.progress >= 90 && !guessResetNum) || forceGuess) {
                    timesGuessed++;
                    guessResetNum += 10;
                    await aki.win();
                    const guess = aki.answers.filter(g => !guessBlacklist.includes(g.id))[0];
                    if (!guess) {
                        await message.channel.send('**I Can\'t Think of Anyone!**');
                        win = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    guessBlacklist.push(guess.id);
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                        .setColor('RED')
                        .setTitle(`I'm ${Math.round(guess.proba * 100)}% Sure It's...`)
                        .setDescription(`**${guess.name}${guess.description ? `\nProfession - ${guess.description}` : ''}\nRanking - ${guess.ranking}\nType Yes/No To Confirm!**`)
                        .setImage(guess.absolute_picture_path || null)
                        .setFooter(forceGuess ? 'Final Guess' : `Guesses - ${timesGuessed}`);
                    await message.channel.send(embed);
                    const verification = await verify(message.channel, message.author);
                    if (verification === 0) {
                        win = 'time';
                        break;
                    } else if (verification) {
                        win = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        const exmessage = timesGuessed >= 3 || forceGuess ? 'I Give Up!' : 'I Can Keep Going!';
                        await message.channel.send(`**Hmm... Is That so? ${exmessage}**`);
                        if (timesGuessed >= 3 || forceGuess) {
                            win = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
            if (win === 'time') return message.channel.send('**I Guess Your Silence Means I Have Won!**');
            if (win) return message.channel.send('**You Have Defeated Me This Time!**');
            return message.channel.send('**Guessed Right One More Time! I Love Playing With You!**');
        } catch (err) {
            ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
            return message.channel.send(`**Server Down, Try again later!**`);
        };
    }
};
```

further details:
discord.js (v12)
node version (v14.15.3)

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: So `ops` is undefined

Comment: @epascarello no it is defined

Comment: @Som3a12 No, it's `undefined`. Check how you call `execute(message, args, Discord, client, ops)`. I'm pretty sure you forgot to pass `ops`.

Comment: Its defined as an argument, but its value is undefined.....

Comment: whats the solution then @ZsoltMeszaros - @ epascarello

Comment: i cant figure it out at all till now